# How to Merge Two List in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

This is my controller:

```
List<Equipement> equipements = equipementService.findEquipmentsByAssignment(affectationId);
List<Equipement> equipements2 = equipementService.selectSotck();
```

How can you merge two lists into one?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? concatenate the two? remove duplicates? something else?

Comment: The Java API documentation is your friend: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#addAll(int,java.util.Collection)

Comment: yes i have two list equipements and equipements2, i want to concatenate in one list "equipements3" for example

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of java you use and if you are allowed to use external libs (like Guava), but here you will find few examples for most scenarios https://www.techiedelight.com/join-two-lists-java/

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.elfayq.stock.services.impl;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.elfayq.stock.dao.IEquipementDao;
import com.elfayq.stock.entities.Equipement;
import com.elfayq.stock.services.IEquipementService;
//L'annotation transactionnel pour dire que la classe contient des m�thode de transaction avec la base de donn�es
@Transactional
public class EquipementServiceImpl implements IEquipementService{

private IEquipementDao equipementsDao;
    
public void setEquipementsDao(IEquipementDao equipementsDao) {
this.equipementsDao = equipementsDao;
}
    
@Override
public Equipement save(Equipement entity) {
return equipementsDao.save(entity);
}

@Override
public Equipement update(Equipement entity) {   
return equipementsDao.update(entity);
}

@Override
public List<Equipement> selectAll() {   
return equipementsDao.selectAll();
}

@Override
public List<Equipement> selectAll(String sortField, String sort) {      
return equipementsDao.selectAll(sortField, sort);
}

@Override
public void remove(Long id) {
equipementsDao.remove(id);  
}
    
@Override
public List<Equipement> selectSotck() {     
return equipementsDao.selectAllByField("alloted", "0");
}
    
@Override
public List<Equipement> findEquipmentsByAssignment(Long affectionId) {      
return equipementsDao.selectAllByField("idAffectation",String.valueOf(affectionId));
}

@Override
public Equipement getById(Long id) {        
return equipementsDao.getById(id);
}

@Override
public Equipement findOne(String paramName, Object paramValue) {
return equipementsDao.findOne(paramName, paramValue);
}

@Override
public Equipement findOne(String[] paramNames, Object[] paramValues) {  
return equipementsDao.findOne(paramNames, paramValues);
}

@Override
public int findCountBy(String paramName, String paramValue) {   
return equipementsDao.findCountBy(paramName, paramValue);
}
    
public List<Equipement> addAll() {
{
List<Equipement> list = list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
list.addAll(list2);
return list;
}
    
}
```

Comment: this is my service implementation

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Stream.concat` for the streams of the two lists:

```java
public List<Equipement> addAll() {
    return Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or `flatMap` for the list of lists:

```java
public List<Equipement> addAll() {
    return Arrays.stream(Arrays.asList(list1, list2))
                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or simply `List.addAll`:

```java
public List<Equipement> addAll() {
    List<Equipement> all = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    all.addAll(list2);
    return all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, if you don't need deduplication:

```
List<String> x = ...;
List<String> y = ...;
x.addAll(y);
```